# Recommended approach for project management in F#

Tags: .net, f#

What is the recommended approach for platform-independent and IDE-independent project management for F# projects.

Exploring for solutions I came across [ProjectScaffold](https://github.com/fsprojects/ProjectScaffold), [Forge](https://github.com/fsprojects/Forge) and [Projekt](http://fsprojects.github.io/Projekt/), all of which seem to be actively maintained under the same organization (fsprojects).

It is not obvious how these projects are related and if there is a recommended solution that is best suited for a cross platform F# project being written from scratch.

What are the potential pitfalls with manually managing `.fsproj` files if paket is already being used for dependency management.

Comment: It might be opinion based, but it would be quite useful to have a good overview.

Comment: This would work better as a Documentation page, if anyone's up for writing one.

Comment: Maybe it could be a good idea to create github repository to gather a guidlines and best practices for f# developers. I found something similar for PowerShell https://github.com/PoshCode/PowerShellPracticeAndStyle

Comment: Something like that would be very helpful to a lot of newcomers.

Comment: I went with forge as Ionide [uses it](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/fsharp/tutorials/getting-started/getting-started-vscode) by default and it worked without any hiccups (in Ionide as well as through the CLI).